# Class 'yii\jui\DatePicker' not found (Not a duplicate one)!

Tags: yii2, datapicker

I used composer to install it. I checked all needed files in vendor/yiisoft/yii2-jui existing. The extensions.php is all right. I have "use yii\jui\DatePicker;" in my file, But it still doesn't work.
How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You have to provide some code. Show us the essential parts. And why do you think it is not a duplicate? Which questions have you already read and that didn't help?

Comment: Thanks for welcome. I have fixed it by accident.  I just read all questions with key word "Class 'yii\jui\DatePicker' not found" . Thank you all the same.

Comment: You can answer your own question to help others. Or you can delete your question. The current state (unclear question without answer) just polutes SO and doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are missing Composer Asset Plugin. After you install Composer, run this command:

```
php composer.phar global require "fxp/composer-asset-plugin:~1.0.3"
```

after that, just to be safe run the self-update:

```
composer self-update
```

At this point you should probably get your GitHub credentials ready, because when you run `composer update`, the updater will start downloading loads of missing stuff (including `Jui` Asset), which will most likely hit the GitHub unauthorized request limit.

Hope this helps!